# XSLT to export FMPXMLRESULT xml document into Excel

Tags: xml, xslt, filemaker

I want to export FileMaker table data to an excel sheet with having some formatting. Means the columns of the excel sheet will having some background color, header will have some color formatting etc.. So my output excel sheet after export action should be a formatted excel sheet.

My way of approach to this process is like below:

1 > In FileMaker Export step exporting the file as Test.xls and XML as file type.

2 > Selecting FMPXMLRESULT as grammar. Selecting some field to be export.

In this process **i need one XSLT which can transform FMPXMLRESULT xml data to an excel sheet**. Regarding data formatting, CSS files are with me. I need to embed these CSS files with in that XSL style sheet. So when we will open that Test.xls file it will be a formatted spreadsheet.

So if someone have experience of using XSLT which can transform FMPXMLRESULT xml data to an excel sheet it will be a great help for me.

Please advice me in this direction.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform FileMaker XML into [Spreadsheet ML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066%28office.10%29.aspx). You cannot use CSS there; you'll have to define formatting with Style elements. A good way would be to prepare a sample of what you're going to accomplish in Excel, save it as Spreadsheet ML (in the save dialog it will be something like 'Excel 2003 XML') and use it as a template. Otherwise it's a pretty standard XSLT transformation.